# Embed an image in a mail and send it with Linux mail to Outlook 2007

Tags: linux, image, email, embed, outlook-2007

How to send a HTML email with embedded image to Outlook 2007 using Linux's mail command.

I tried to send the following, but it doesn't work.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0l...IADs=" />
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Will not work in Outlook 2007, since it doesn't support data_uri scheme.
The only way is to get this done is by using creating multipart/related mail setting the content-id for the image then displaying.